# How can I "bookmark" certain offsets in Kafka internally?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If I have a consumer with auto-commit enabled, is there still a way to make kafka mark or remember a certain offset and access this offset via a given name? Or do I need to store the offset externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka doesn't provide any such feature. You'll have to store offsets externally.